# Is docker volume with o+w permissions a bad practice?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

How bad idea is to create a volume that is writable for other users (o+w)?

I have a container that can create some files. I want user, who is running this container, to be able to use those files, in particular modify them.

What I did is that I've created a volume inside my Dockerfile and then, in the entrypoint I changed its owner and permissions to o+w. At the end, I used gosu to step down from the root.

I wonder if this can be somehow insecure or bad practice?
IMO it's okay as my container, after using gosu, runs as non-root user. The only "problem" is that user can delete host directory that is used as volume.

Comment: It's very slightly better than `chmod 0777` but still Not A Best Practice.  Can you `docker run -u` the container with the right (numeric) user ID, or make the directory group-writable and share a (numeric) group ID?

Comment: I assume that when running with `-u`, I could create volume directory with the same owner I run docker command?

So instead of 


`RUN mkdir output  && chown jellyfish:jellyfish /output VOLUME output/`


I would do

`RUN mkdir output VOLUME output/`

Comment: The volume mount hides everything about the target directory, including its owner.  If it's a mount point then `RUN chown` won't do anything, and the `jellyfish` user in the container might not have the same numeric user ID as the host user.  You also don't need to explicitly declare a `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile; you can still mount a volume without it, and it has some confusing side effects.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! One more thing I wonder about is why in the official redis image they do `RUN mkdir /data && chown redis:redis /data`. When you run it as non-root user and mount volume (so using options `-u` and `-v`), wouldn't be it like non-root user is trying to save something to the directory owned by `redis:redis`?

Comment: That setup is there so if you _don't_ mount a volume explicitly, Docker will create an anonymous volume, and it will be owned by the default non-root user created in the Dockerfile.  If you `docker run -v ...:/data` then the host directory will hide the (empty) image directory, and the container directory will be owned by the numeric owner of the host directory.